# Does GCM tokens work after April 11th 2019 if i only make changes to the console and server side?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a legacy system and most of the android clients use Google messaging cloud. As of April 2019, GCM is going to be completely removed. Will the GCM tokens on my old android clients work if I migrate only the server side to FCM?
I read in the FAQ's that FCM do support GCM tokens but I am confused if it is only till April 11th 2019 or indefinitely?

Comment: I am trying to analyse this particular situation ->  If I don't update my client code and I update only the server code and make changes on the google console. Will it work for my old clients? It would really help me analyse to go forward with the changes or not! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq):

> **Will my existing GCM tokens and token handling still work?**
>
> Your GCM and FCM registration tokens are mutually interchangeable; you can send to existing GCM tokens through the FCM HTTP server APIs. For GCM and FCM token handling, remember:
>
> - If you store and send to specific tokens, be sure to implement the token refresh method to ensure your tokens are always up to date
> - iOS devs should avoid calling `.getToken(authorizedEntity,scope)` unless there is a need to enable multiple senders. Use `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` instead.

Also from this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/04/time-to-upgrade-from-gcm-to-fcm.html):

> If you have projects that are still using the GCM APIs, you will need to update your client and server code to use FCM before April 11, 2019. But rest assured, your existing GCM tokens will continue to work with FCM so you won't lose the ability to send messages to your existing users.

In my understanding, only the client and server code should be updated before April 11, 2019. If you have existing GCM tokens, you’ll still be able to use them to send notifications. This statement is also true for GCM tokens that you generate in the future.